# Run code off the main thread?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firefox-addon, synchronous

I know it's possible to run `js-ctypes` off the main thread so it acts async by using `ChromeWorker`. But `ChromeWorker`s can't use XPCOM.

So I was wondering if there is a way to run other synchronous stuff off the main thread?

I was hoping to use it for things like `nsIZipWriter`, nsIToolkitProfileService::Lock/Unlock`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, the only way to run off-the-main-thread code is `WebWorker`/`ChromeWorker`, which indeed does not have XPCOM access.

Actually, there used to be a way to use XPCOM from workers, and I was initially upset when it got removed again, but now I appreciate that it was the right thing to do: Much (most?) of XPCOM is not thread-safe, not even when using what appears to be self-contained instances of XPCOM classes, because in the end many of things end up calling some non-thread-safe services as part of their implementation. This leads to data and/or memory corruption and eventual crashes and data loss. Problem here was/is that it does not always corrupt memory, because there is not always a data race, and instead just causes havoc each X-times you run the code. People often used to develop and test their stuff and it happened to worked or at least looked like it worked, but once more people (aka. the users) started executing code, crashes started to pile up.

It is possible to run code off-the-main-thread in C++ code, but it has the same problem, much of XPCOM not being thread-safe, and therefore you'll need to be vary careful what you run in a different thread, i.e. only access stuff that was explicitly marked thread-safe, but even with such a marker there might be thread-safety bugs.

So, you cannot use XPCOM in another thread from JS (unless there are dedicated components doing this for you, like `nsIAsyncStreamCopier`) and even running XPCOM in another thread from C++ requires a lot of knowledge, skill and time to debug things if there are crashes after all.

If you really want to, then things like a zip-writer could be reasonably easy implemented in JS and run in a Worker. E.g. the zip format isn't particularly hard to implement, in particular if you don't need actual compression, and OS.File allows you to mostly conveniently do file I/O from a worker.

Comment: Ah ok thanks man. The `nsIZipWriter` isn't that big a deal but I'm interested to learn how to do that in js, ill ask that q someday :) I had no idea we can do so much in js (like that ico conversion with the help of ctypes). The main thing I wanted to do async was lockProfilePath: https://gist.github.com/yajd/9927658  -- but dang ok so not possible huh? :(

Comment: Well, you can always look at the implementation to see it it would be possible to re-implement it using a Worker (with or without c-types) safely. `lockProfilePath` looks pretty nasty, in particular because it is internally tracked in the Firefox instance to some extend (and you cannot really re-implement that in a compatible fashion), so I wouldn't try to re-implement that!

Comment: haha thx for warning, is it an expensive opoeration? like i know lots of things dont need to be made async. how can i tell if its bogging my computer down?

Comment: man so im doing some synchronus stuff on panel showing (the main Panel-UI-popup) and it is noticeable slowing down the animation :( Is there any way to run sync stuff without slowing the fade in and animation of the panel?

Comment: hey man what about this thing i just found __[nsIThreadManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338221/run-synchronus-code-off-main-thread)__, would this run sync code off of the main thread?

Comment: That is what C++ code would use. You can implement and dispatch `nsIRunnable` to `nsIThread`. However, when the `nsIRunnable` is implemented in Javascript, you're only allowed to dispatch it to the main thread again, but not to other threads. Using `nsIThreadManager`, you can create new threads but you **cannot** run JS code on the new threads.

Comment: I don't understand that comment totally, does that basically mean no its not possible to run js off the main thread (even with nsIRunnable)?

Answer (score 1):

I think yes you can run sync stuff in an async way.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Threads

Comment: oh wow interesting. but i think @nmaier said these methods are outdated. :(